# c pre-processor parameters replacement rules

Tags: c

```
#define mytype __mytype
#define f1(in)\
  call##in
f1(mytype)
```

Doing `gcc -E file.c` outputs `callmytype`.

Adding a new macro in between changes the output:

```
#define mytype __mytype
#define f1(in)\
  call##in
#define f2(in)\
  f1(in)
f2(mytype)
```

outputs `call__mytype`.

I'm guessing the pre-processor doesn't replace `mytype` with `__mytype` when it's being passed as a parameter? Parameters are matched as is without a change?